# python calling c# interface

Tags: c#, python, interface

There is an interface in C# library that I'm trying to use in Python.

This is how I use it in c#:

```
using MyDll.MyClass; 
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 MyClass myclas= new MyClass();
 IMyClassInterface myInterface = null;

 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myInterface = (IMyClassInterface)myclas.GetService(computer, port, MyClass.ServiceName.RUNTIME_CONTROL); } }
```

The question is how to start the same service in python using c# interface from c# dll? 
The same thing above, I want to also implement in python. Python code Like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\foldername")
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Program Files\foldername\MyDll.MyClass")
from MyDll.MyClass import MyClass

def OnRun(self, userExcInst):
    myInterface = MyClass()
    myInterface = (IMyClassInterface)myclas.GetService(computer, port, MyClass.ServiceName.RUNTIME_CONTROL); #??? This is what I am trying to implement
```

As the result, I want to start the service using c# dll in python

Comment: I think what you will need is to use http://www.swig.org/, you can create your library on C# and call from your python service/script